# Pandas groupby - count unique into separate columns per group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to do a groupby where in one column I have string categorical data:

```
ID   cat_1   cat_2
11   'OG'    'ASD'
11   'LOL'   'ASD' 
11   'OG'    'DFG' 
22   'LOL'   'DFG'
22   'OG'    'DFG'
```

And I'm trying to group by the ID, and aggregate the string data into a numeric feature, namely, the counts of occurrences for each category. So the outcome would be:

```
ID  OG  LOL  ASD  DFG
11   2    1    2    1
22   1    1    0    2
```

How can I achieve this in pandas? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure of the output? How do you get 22/ASD = 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pd.get_dummies` with `groupby` and `stack`:

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(df.set_index("ID").stack()).groupby("ID").sum()
    ASD  DFG  LOL  OG
ID                   
11    2    1    1   2
22    0    2    1   1
```

Comment: `pd.get_dummies(df).groupby("ID").sum()`

Comment: but it gives different results than your code.

Comment: @lte__ - The `df` I used in my example didn't have "ID" as the index. The `stack()` is so that the columns in the output match your output instead of having "cat_1_LOL" "cat_2_ASD" etc.

Comment: gotcha. And why do you think this gives a different result than `pd.get_dummies(df).groupby("ID").sum()`?

Comment: I get the exact same result with your code too. Just the order of the columns is different.

Comment: ah gotcha I figured it out. You're forcing the ID to the the key, while in my dataset the "ID" is not unique, that's the difference. I made a wrong parallel to my use case. So in theory they should both give the same results, right? If ID is in fact unique, as it should be! :D

Comment: @lte__ - Indeed :)

Answer (score 2):

You can stack/value_counts/unstack:

```
(df.set_index('ID')
   .stack()
   .groupby('ID')
   .value_counts()
   .unstack(fill_value=0)
)
```

*NB. you can add `.reset_index()` if you want all columns*

output:

```
    ASD  DFG  LOL  OG
ID                   
11    2    1    1   2
22    0    2    1   1
```